# Is it possible to pass an object from my DataBase through session in an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, session, post

```
router.post('/order', (req, res) => {
    let order = req.body;
    userSession.createOrderSession(req, order);
    console.log("WWW",req.session.order);
    res.render("store",{
        productTitle: req.session.order.title,
        productPrice: req.session.order.price,
        productImage: req.session.order.imageSrc
    });
});
```

Here is my back-end

```
createOrderSession(req, order) {
        const newOrder = {
            "title": order.title,
            "price": order.price,
            "imageSrc": order.imageSrc
        };
        req.session.order = newOrder;
        return newOrder;
    },
```

And here is where I create my session, and on every key the data comes right from the db, but I can't pass it forward to another HTML element for example in a div in the Shopping cart.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <header class="main-header">
            {{>navigation}}
        </header>
        <section class="store-container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Shoes</h2>
            {{#each productName}}
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title"> {{name}}</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-photo" src="images/nike.jpeg" >
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">{{price}} $</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-parent">
        <section class="cart-container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Cart</h2>
            <div class="cart-rows">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">Item</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">Price</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">Quantity</span>
            </div>

            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button" id="store">Purchase</button>
        </section>
    </div>
    {{>footerbtm}}

</body>
```

Here is the store template. I hope it helps

Comment: This is essentially about making server data available to the client-side JS code (because inserting data into HTML is already covered by passing the data to `res.render` and using it in the template); two common ways are a) output `<script>data = { ... };</script>` and b) request the data from a dedicated endpoint via fetch(). So yes, trivially possible. Can you post your store template?

Comment: I added the store template.

Comment: Look at your `res.render("store", ...)` call. The data you pass here is the data that is available to make loops and insert data in the template. Your are not using any of the three passed variables, instead you're using `productName` as if it's an array? No idea what's happening there.